# Unity, Follow a rolling ball and be able to rotate around it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation

I want to be able to follow a rolling ball (which I can do by itself) and I want to be able to rotate around the ball while holding right click (which I can do by itself as well) but when I try to combine these 2 I get unwanted results.

In the code below you can see that if I just wanted to rotate around the ball my "RotateAround" takes care of that no problem and if I just wanted to follow the ball wherever it goes with the camera being the same distance away and angle then my _offset takes care of that.  When I try to combine the 2 to have it follow the ball and be able to rotate the camera (with right click) at the same time the camera just stops following the ball.

I figured since you can follow the ball with the _offset by itself which I found on the Unity tutorials that when the position is changed with RotateAround that _offset would take care of keeping the camera in the new position.  This script by the way is on my Camera GameObject.

```
void Start()
{
    _offset = CamFollowStartSpot.position - Ball.transform.position;
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        _transform.RotateAround(Ball.transform.position, Vector3.up, 20 * Time.deltaTime);
        _offset = _transform.position - Ball.transform.position;
    }
    _transform.position = Ball.transform.position + _offset;
}
```

Comment: you do it with *two separate game objects*, one wrapping the other

Comment: @JoeBlow Can you explain what you mean by wrapping the other please.

Comment: i just mean sitting one game object inside another, you might have three or four deep.  at one level you would "turn" and at the next level you would "orbit" or whatever.  with different scripts on each level.  it's a common technique .. experiment with it when you have time!

Comment: @JoeBlow Thanks for the suggestion but the current answer to the problem I am having is much simpler and does the trick.  The last parameter in RotateAround may have been misleading but it was going to be used to when you hold right click and move your mouse you can move around the rolling ball in the game.  The issue I was having was being able to rotate my camera around the ball as it was moving and I just had code in the wrong order.

Comment: sure, good luck and have fun!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong, it was when I was setting my position at the end.  The code below needed to be called before the IF statement to check for my mouse click input.

```
_transform.position = Ball.transform.position + _offset;
```

The correct way is in the code below.

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    _transform.position = Ball.transform.position + _offset;
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        _transform.RotateAround(Ball.transform.position, Vector3.up, 20 * Time.deltaTime);
        _offset = _transform.position - Ball.transform.position;
    }
}
```